# Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter

Tags: c#, operators

I'm getting the error in the title, can someone tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
public class Book
{
    public string Distributor { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public Book(string distributor, string name, int amount, double price)
    {
        this.Distributor = distributor;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Amount = amount;
        this.Price = price;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        string line = string.Format("| {0,15} | {1,15} | {2,5} | {3,6} |", Distributor, Name, Amount, Price);
        return line;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Book book = obj as Book;
        return book.Price == Price;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Price.GetHashCode();
    }
    public static Book operator >= (Book book1, Book book2) //the error here
    {
        Book temp = new Book();
        if (book1.Name == book2.Name && book1.Price > book2.Price)
            temp = book1;
        return temp;
    }
    public static Book operator <= (Book book1, Book book2) // and here
    {
        Book temp = new Book();
        if (book1.Name == book2.Name && book1.Price < book2.Price)
            temp = book2;
        return temp;
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error in the 'operator' lines. I Want the operator '>=' and '<=' to find books with the same name and which one costs more.

Comment: You have no Book constructor that accepts zero arguments. It is clearly stated in the error message from the compiler.

Comment: What construtor do I need?

Comment: You need an empty constructor _public Book() { }_ Usually this empty constructor is automatically defined but when you create your own constructor then it is no more added automatically

Comment: The `>=` and `<=` operators should return `bool`, not `Book`. That should take care of your constructor problam as well since you won't be creating a book inside the operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I Want the operator '>=' and '<=' to find books with the same name and which one costs more.

That's not what those operators do. They tell you whether one value is *less/greater than or equal to another*. Therefore, they should return `bool` instead of `Book`.  You also need to decide what to return if they have different names:

```
public static bool operator >= (Book book1, Book book2)
{
    if (book1.Name == book2.Name)
       return (book1.Price >= book2.Price);
    else
       return ?? what do you want to return here ??
}
public static bool operator <= (Book book1, Book book2)
{
    if (book1.Name == book2.Name)
       return (book1.Price <= book2.Price);
    else
       return ?? what do you want to return here ??
}
```

If this is really what you are trying to do, then I would encourage you to also overload the `<` and `>` operators.

Comment: Also the null check should be defined in some way.